# Attribute [ngSwitch] is not allowed here, this is what IntelliJ IDEA 2016 tells me for an Angular2 template, why?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, angular

Everything seems to work fine, I have intellisense and such. However, when I run precommit inspections I have tons of warnings, like:

```
Warning:(8, 58) Attribute [ngSwitch] is not allowed here
Warning:(9, 42) Attribute [attr.for] is not allowed here
Warning:(10, 14) Attribute *ngSwitchCase is not allowed here
Warning:(11, 32) Attribute *ngFor is not allowed here
Warning:(12, 38) Attribute [attr.for] is not allowed here
...
```

And so forth and so forth.

How do I instruct the IDEA that these are fine? I do not want to disable the inspection blindly, but not sure if there is a way to avoid it.

**EDIT 1**

I have AngularJS plugin already installed:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the [AngularJS Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971?pr=idea) to add support?

Comment: I already have it - see **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 10):

I've had this problem on and off over the past few months. I even posted an [issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207638905-Angular-2-HTML-template-and-TSLint-issues) with Jetbrains and the thread seems to have received much attention since.

**I just resolved the problem by removing my .idea directory for the project and re-opening the IDE**.

Comment: Worked even for me with latest IntelliJ 2018.3